Cannot see NVMe drives Broadcom MegaRAID 9540-8i and Supermicro server
I have a Broadcom MegaRAID 9540-8i controller on a Supermicro SYS-6029P-WTRT server.
I bought a cable 05-60002-00 according to the specification, I plugged it into the white connectors on the backplane BPN-SAS3-826A-N4.
If I plug the controller into SAS disks (slot 0-7) on the backplane, I can see everything and the disks are loaded and the backplane is visible in the controller in the bios.
But if I plug the wire into the white connectors (NVMe), then SAS NVMe disks (slots 8-11) are not visible and the backplane is not detected in the controller.
Has anyone experienced this, maybe even with a different controller. What could be the solution?
